# How to get inner html of li via id of parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to get inner html of li which is in div. Please see my code

```
<div id="tabs" style="border:none !important;">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1" class="active">Flight</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Hotel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Car Rental</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Cruise</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Not sharing full code as no need. Is there a simple way to get inner html of li using the parent div id(tabs).

Comment: Which `LI`? There are 4 `LI`s in your code. And you should try something first.

Comment: Maybe you wrote it, but I didn't see your effort. Please share the code you tried.

Comment: @panther what use if i will share that code as that was not working but i can share the error which i got..

Comment: looking for something like $("ul li")

Comment: @ Leo the lion please correct  your `html`  structure

Comment: @ozil I've already sent in an edit request to fix it.

Comment: @Leothelion That is no excuse to not go through and reformat your code for stack overflow. I spend so many hours changing peoples code who don't fix it themselves.

Comment: try to use {selector}.innerHTML

Comment: @Tommy thanx for your tip but then  tell me what change it will make if i will put my 100 lines of code when i only need solution of few lines and i showed them?

Comment: @Leothelion You should always treat the code box you are using as a stand alone file. i.e. indent everything properly from all the way to the left. Follow standard conventions for indentation html should either be 2 or 4 space indents. Examples should be complete and basically self sufficient pieces of code that one could easily run or view.

Comment: @Leothelion I didn't down vote you to be clear. And my edit fixed the spacing issues in your code added a close tag to a div and removed an open div that appeared to not have any context to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs li").each(function(){
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t2o3vppa/1/

Comment: sorry but i just want to get one li value at one time..sorry m not expert in jquery so

Comment: @Leothelion I edited my answer, it will now show an alert for each li value, so 4 alerts in this case.

Comment: your answer is not what i am looking for but i got idea from your answer so thank you..:)

Comment: @Leothelion You are welcome. If you need more help, tell me a bit more what you really want to do, I just showed here how to get each `LI` innerHTML :)

Answer (score 0):

Yoyu can get your list items simply by using jquery selectors as

```
var listItems = $('#tabs ul li');
for(i=0;i<listItems.length;i++)
{
    alert(listItems.eq(i).html());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have JQuery, you can have something like this :

```
$("#tabs").find("li").each(function(index, element) {
    console.log($(this).html()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$("#tabs").find("ul li").each(function(){alert($(this).text())})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr=[];
$("#tabs").find("li").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    var obj = {};
    obj['href'] = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    obj['li'] = $(this).html();
    arr.push(obj);
});
console.log(arr);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh2epbLr/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tabs ul li').each(function () {
    var contenu = $(this).html();
});
```

You can also case each li :

```
 $('#tabs ul li').each(function () {
        $content_of_li = $(this).html(); // $(this) is the li
        $tab_id = $(this).attr('id').substr(4,1); // you get : 1,2,3,4...
        switch($tab_id ) {
            case 1:/*do that*/;break;
            case2...
            case3...
        }
});
```